SignalR via MassTransit not able to create a topic on azure service bus
We are running into a bit of a strange error on one of our environments. I am going to try and give as much context as I possibly can.
We are using signalR with MassTransit as the backplane and we currently have about 4 hubs registered with signalR. These hubs include DiaryHub, ConsultationHub, InvoiceNoteHub and ArchiveHub. In our develop and QA environment these hubs register correctly and the pods are able to start up, but in our UAT environment, the pods fail to start up waiting for the Masstransit registration process to complete (our liveness probe kills the pod as it is not reachable during this hanging period). We have gotten as far as identifying the ArchiveHub as the culprit, we did this by process of elimination, the registration process only works if the archive hub is excluded from the SignalR registration.
We are using the Azure service bus as our message broker. The biggest problem is that the actual code did not change the issue started occurring on Tuesday morning after our AKS Cluster started up again (we stop the test environment cluster every night and start it up again in the morning for cost-saving purposes).
We have turned debugging logs on for our pods to ensure nothing is missed as there are no errors happening. these are the only logs that seem to point to anything.
[13:40:07 DBG] Endpoint Faulted: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fyi6drbdqk3m4grm?autodelete=300
MassTransit.ServiceBusConnectionException: ReceiveTransport faulted: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fyi6drbdqk3m4grm?autodelete=300
---> Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: Topic was not found (MessagingEntityNotFound)
---> Azure.RequestFailedException: <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title><subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle><id>uuid:8837b91b-d5b6-43c7-8861-3b58cabd7b09;id=47650</id><updated>2024-07-25T13:40:07Z</updated><generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator></feed>
Status: 200 (OK)

Content:
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title><subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle><id>uuid:8837b91b-d5b6-43c7-8861-3b58cabd7b09;id=47650</id><updated>2024-07-25T13:40:07Z</updated><generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator></feed>

Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2024 13:40:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8

  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.TopicPropertiesExtensions.ParseResponseAsync(Response response, ClientDiagnostics diagnostics)
  at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClient.GetTopicAsync(String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusConnectionContext.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<GetTopicAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Contexts/ServiceBusConnectionContext.cs:line 304
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusConnectionContext.RunOperation[T](Func`1 operation) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Contexts/ServiceBusConnectionContext.cs:line 366
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusConnectionContext.CreateTopic(CreateTopicOptions createTopicOptions) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Contexts/ServiceBusConnectionContext.cs:line 111
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Middleware.ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter`1.ConfigureTopology(ConnectionContext context) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Middleware/ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter.cs:line 63
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Middleware.ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<ConfigureTopology>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Middleware/ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
  at MassTransit.PipeExtensions.OneTimeSetup[T](PipeContext context, Func`2 setupMethod, PayloadFactory`1 payloadFactory) in /_/src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Middleware/PipeExtensions.cs:line 106
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Middleware.ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter`1.ConfigureTopology(NamespaceContext context) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Middleware/ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter.cs:line 50
  at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Middleware.ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter`1.Send(ClientContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Middleware/ConfigureServiceBusTopologyFilter.cs:line 29
  at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Agents/PipeContextSupervisor.cs:line 55
  at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Agents/PipeContextSupervisor.cs:line 61
  at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Agents/PipeContextSupervisor.cs:line 67
  at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveTransport`1.ReceiveTransportAgent.RunTransport() in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceiveTransport.cs:line 188
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[13:40:07 DBG] Queue: clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywktbbdqk3m4grc (dead letter, auto-delete: 5m)
[13:40:08 DBG] Creating subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-sbo8z3 MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/Group--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fyw893bdqk3m4grc
[13:40:08 DBG] Creating subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-e17bc5 MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/User--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywceabdqk3m4grc
[13:40:08 DBG] Subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-sbo8z3 (MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/Group--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> http://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fyw893bdqk3m4grc)
[13:40:08 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fyw893bdqk3m4grc?autodelete=300
[13:40:08 DBG] Subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-e17bc5 (MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/User--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> http://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywceabdqk3m4grc)
[13:40:08 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywceabdqk3m4grc?autodelete=300
[13:40:08 DBG] Creating subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-6q3no8 MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/Connection--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywfmrbdqk3m4grc
[13:40:08 DBG] Subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-6q3no8 (MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/Connection--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> http://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywfmrbdqk3m4grc)
[13:40:08 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywfmrbdqk3m4grc?autodelete=300
[13:40:08 DBG] Creating subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-th43ft MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/GroupManagement--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywktbbdqk3m4grc
[13:40:08 DBG] Subscription clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archiveh-th43ft (MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/GroupManagement--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub-- -> http://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywktbbdqk3m4grc)
[13:40:08 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/clinical56f857_ClinicalApi_signalr_archivehub_yryyyyg4d3fywktbbdqk3m4grc?autodelete=300
[13:40:15 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:40:27 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:40:43 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:41:16 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:41:49 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:42:22 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--
[13:42:52 DBG] Stopping bus: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/ 

"Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--" This log is where the start-up freezes waiting for the change to take place and the "[13:42:52 DBG] Stopping bus: sb://aht-healthone-uat-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/" is where the liveness probe kills the pod.
I have tried to delay the liveness probe to give this process a bit more time (I have set the delay to 10 minutes), but even then the "[13:40:15 DBG] Create topic: MassTransit.SignalR.Contracts/All--Clinical.Application.Sockets/ArchiveHub--" just continues until the pod eventually gets recycled by Kubernetes.
The Topic not found error is also thrown when the pod gets recycled because it cannot find the topic in question.
The one topic is missing in this specific environment, I will attach an image of our UAT and QA environments next to each other and you will see that the topic "masstransit.signalr.contracts~all--clinical.application.sockets~archivehub--" is the missing topic which is the one that gets stuck on during the create step mententioned above.
Environment Comparison
We have tried all of the following:

Tried to create the topic manually via the Azure portal (As you can see in the picture above the topic cannot be created manually because it does not meet the requirements of the regex, but somehow masstransit can normally create them).
I have tried creating the topic manually via the CLI as well.
We have tried cleaning up the exisitng queues and topics using a bulk delete script while the service was down.
We have restarted the entire Cluster and even recycled all the nodes in the cluster as well.


If you cannot create it via the portal because the name validation fails, then it is not a legal topic name.  Just because it happened to work by coincidence via the old ATOM service previously, that does not mean that it was intended to work.  The Service Bus service team has been working to lock down potential gaps in validation/security over the last few months.   This seems to fall into that bucket.

@JesseSquire Thank you for the response, so currently these topics are created by MassTransit itself, are we saying this should be logged as a bug against MassTransit because there is a potential policy change on the Azure service bus?
The main concern with the above is this works in all other environments and even works in the environment in question for other topics created by MassTransit which uses the same naming convention.
We have even deleted some topics on that environment and they were also recreated successfully

From the error, Mass Transit is using the official Azure SDK package and its admin client to create the topic.  The admin client talks to a legacy ATOM service for entity manipulation, since Service Bus does not expose the functionality from its AMQP interface.  That ATOM service is old and seemingly was not performing the correct validation.  My best guess is that the Service Bus team simply forgot to update it when they updated the ARM rules.  With the current security focus, many of these old mistakes are being corrected by the service.  Mass Transit has no control here.
